# How Do I Create a Windows Services for Gnu shell and Execute a Command on Opening without it Closing after completion?

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I was following along with this blog here - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/a-guide-to-invoking-wsl/ - and it seems to get at what I'm trying to do ALMOST.

Specifically, I'd like to create several tabs using WSL in Windows Terminal (though this doesn't matter), have each one stay open, but execute a different script in each.

So, this might be something like (creating two tabs for app1 and creating a third tab for app2):

```
wsl "bash -c cd app1"
wsl "bash -c cd app1"
wsl "bash -c cd app2"
```

Unfortunately, bash closes and exits after each.

I thought I could work around this by doing something like:

```
wsl "bash -c cd app1; bash"
```

But the follow on bash is not in a new spawned shell, losing all context from the previous ones.

Any suggestions here?

Comment: Did you mean `bash -c 'cd app1; bash'`?

Comment: It is hard to workout what you are trying to do. After much effort, my guess is something about starting bash in a specified directory. And something (as yet un-discovered) about services.